# How can I organize my data to be in one line using Python?

Tags: python

**Data description:** 
My data file ExpData.txt, [included here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4omjm386iemyur/ExpData.txt?dl=0), contains the experiment results involving multiple subjects.

1) The 1st column corresponds to 4-digit subject IDs

2) The 2nd column corresponds to response times. (The number of trials for each subject ranges from 15 to 25.) 
*Looks like this:*

```
   0001   81
   0001   112
   0001   125
   0001   99
   0001   120
```

**Aim:** 
I need to be able to read this data file and re-format the data with one subject per line (to make it easier to analyze statistically). In other words, each line starts with a subject ID, followed by the response times for that subject, sorted in the ascending order and separated by a space. 
*Should look like this:*

```
0001 80 81 . . . 120 125
0003 77 78 . . . 109 110 112 117 120 123
0005 78 78 . . . 120 120
-. . .
```

I need to save the reformatted data as a separate data file called ExpDataReformat.txt.

Any ideas on how to do this? or where to even start?

I started by trying to edit this code someone else shared on a post that appends and sorts states and state capitals. Needless to say, I kept getting syntax errors.

```
infile = open('TestData/StateCapitalList.txt','r') 
stateData = infile.read() 
infile.close() 

dataLines = stateData.split('\n') 

state = [] 
capital = [] 

for line in dataLines: 

    if line: 
        iState, iCapital = line.split(',') 
        state.append(iState)     
        capital.append(iCapital) 

outfile = open('TestData/sCapitalList.txt','w') 

capital.sort() 

for iCap in capital: 

    outfile.write(iCap + '\n')  

outfile.close()
```

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: We shouldn't have to download a file to see what your data starts as. Please copy and paste a sample of it here with an [edit]

Comment: None of the lines start with a `-`...

Comment: Are all the response times for each subject consecutive in the file? Related: are the subject IDs in sorted order? If those two are true, the code becomes easier and faster.

Comment: @cricket_007. I did paste a sample of it. It's the part that says : "It looks like this"

Comment: @AlexHall no, none of the lines start with "-". When I was typing my question, I couldn't get it to skip a line and in the list editor it said to add a "-" so I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, all of the response times for each subject are in consecutive order as are the subject ids. The responses are not sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @not_a_robot I started by trying to edit a code someone used to sort states and capitals in ascending order from a text file but I had a bunch of syntax errors and couldn't get it to run not even once :(

Comment: @not_a_robot I added the code I was trying to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('ExpData.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key, value = line.split()
        result[key].append(int(value))

with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for key, value_list in sorted(result.items()):
        outfile.write(' '.join([key] + map(str, sorted(value_list)))
                      + '\n')
```

Comment: I got a syntax error...could it be that I'm using 3.5.2?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jisse\Desktop\5.2c.py", line 12, in <module>
    outfile.write(' '.join([key]+map(str, sorted(value_list)))+'\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a Python 2/3 difference. Make it `list(map(...))`. And that's not a syntax error, it's a type error.

Comment: I do the list(map(...)) only at the end or wherever there is "key"?

Comment: Before asking me this question, did you try anything? Can you make a guess, run it, and see what happens?

Comment: I did. I edited line 12 which is what was highlighted before. But now it just highlights the word "list" in red. I also tried brackets because the "invent with python" book shows these being used, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What does the line say now?

Comment: Only "invalid syntax" with "list" highlighted in red. Nothing else.

Comment: outfile.write(' '.join list(map(str, sorted(value_list)))+'\n')

Comment: I meant `outfile.write(' '.join([key] + list(map(str, sorted(value_list))))`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't include any code in your question, this answer contains none.

You need to open the file, and create an empty dictionary.

Then, for each line in the file, split it into `subject` and `data`. Test to see whether the subject exists as a key in the dictionary. If not, create a dictionary entry for that key whose value is a list containing the single element `data`. If the subject is already present in the dictionary then append `data` to the value.

When the file is exhausted, for each of the keys in the dictionary (in sorted order) output the key value followed the the string made up of joining all the data items with spaces in between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

with open(path) as f:
    it=(line.split() for line in f)
    for k, g in groupby(it, key=lambda e: e[0]):
        print(k, sorted(map(int, (t[1] for t in g))))
```

Prints:

```
0001 [80, 81, 81, 82, 89, 90, 97, 99, 101, 108, 112, 114, 118, 120, 120, 125]
0003 [77, 78, 84, 86, 89, 92, 99, 101, 101, 101, 103, 106, 106, 108, 109, 110, 112, 117, 120, 123]
0005 [78, 78, 83, 86, 87, 89, 95, 104, 109, 110, 113, 114, 115, 119, 120, 120]
0012 [80, 83, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, 99, 100, 101, 101, 101, 104, 108, 110, 113, 113, 113, 120, 122, 124]
0015 [78, 78, 80, 80, 81, 81, 85, 86, 89, 91, 94, 100, 100, 102, 107, 109, 115, 116, 116, 121, 122, 123, 125, 125]
0021 [78, 79, 80, 83, 87, 88, 90, 91, 91, 96, 96, 96, 100, 102, 108, 109, 118, 125]
0024 [76, 78, 78, 83, 87, 88, 88, 89, 92, 96, 96, 103, 107, 108, 108, 108, 111, 112, 113, 119, 119, 120, 122, 123, 125]
0027 [78, 81, 84, 85, 90, 92, 95, 95, 96, 98, 99, 105, 105, 106, 108, 111, 113, 115, 118, 118, 120, 121, 123, 124]
0040 [76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 82, 84, 90, 93, 93, 94, 99, 103, 104, 107, 107, 109, 114, 117, 120, 125]
0041 [75, 80, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 94, 94, 98, 103, 105, 106, 116, 122]
0043 [76, 83, 84, 85, 86, 86, 91, 94, 102, 105, 107, 108, 119, 123, 123, 124, 125]
0044 [81, 81, 83, 85, 85, 86, 86, 92, 95, 98, 98, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 106, 112, 115, 117, 118, 122]
0047 [84, 86, 90, 90, 92, 94, 94, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 105, 109, 111, 113, 115, 116, 118, 119, 120, 121]
0052 [75, 84, 97, 101, 103, 104, 106, 106, 110, 111, 118, 122, 123, 123, 124]
0054 [76, 78, 79, 80, 83, 85, 95, 101, 101, 104, 105, 107, 111, 113, 115, 117, 120, 120]
0057 [75, 75, 75, 76, 79, 80, 82, 82, 83, 84, 86, 90, 93, 94, 95, 95, 96, 99, 100, 102, 102, 112, 116, 119, 120, 124]
0072 [77, 78, 78, 79, 83, 88, 92, 97, 100, 101, 105, 106, 115, 115, 117]
0077 [78, 85, 86, 88, 88, 90, 98, 98, 102, 104, 105, 106, 112, 116, 121, 124]
0080 [76, 82, 84, 85, 90, 94, 100, 101, 107, 107, 109, 110, 112, 115, 115, 118, 118, 121, 122, 125]
0082 [75, 77, 80, 81, 81, 82, 83, 86, 89, 90, 96, 98, 103, 106, 108, 109, 111, 112, 112, 112, 113, 115, 117, 118, 120, 124]
```

Comment: I didn't realize groupby was a thing! Is groupby in python 3.5.2? How might I get it sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I copy/pasted your code with my file path and I got this "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Comment: That is a unicode error from your file. Use a codec and/or encode your source file

Comment: Change the last line to `print(k, " ".join(sorted(map(int, (t[1] for t in g)))))` and you will lose the brackets and commas.